# Cordova won't install on windows 10

Tags: cordova, npm, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed newest (5.0) version od node.js and used cmd to install cordova with:

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Try as i might, i cant complete it. I installation break and display inframtion like this.

I'm trying to reinstall it, after unfortune following of advice given i nother topic about clearing visual's studio cashe. Beofre that i still couldnt build applications correctly, but durring build process atleast i could see in outut window that "cordova is installed" and it seemed to go to next step (failed on android), but now vs tries to get cordova hile building project and fails every time. 
[image: Results in cmd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cordova is not currently compatible with node 5. NPM 3 had breaking changes with the way it lays out packages. I recommend using an older version of node until Cordova is updated.

Comment: When we can expect the nide5(i think from node 5 onwards its supporting angular2) released?

Comment: This should be working on any version greater than 5.4.1.