# Angulars with ionic2 working tutorial

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

We have planned to start our new mobile app using the `cordova+ ionic2` framework. its saying that the angular2 in now in bet release and it will be released to production after 2 month. But the team itself saying that even though the reease is i beta we can start the project. But i don't see much tutorial how can integrate the ionic frameork should integrate in my linux machine. Also please guide me the appropriate editor in linux to work in `ionic2 with angular2`.

Comment: Just FYI - Angular2 is in RC3 now, not in beta. Refer this link for Angular2 latest updates - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Yes. i know this is in beta. But they will release this after two month and we need to start the new project asap. So i think its worth to start the new project in ionic2 rather than ionic1. I fear like thye will support for the angular1 after release of angular2.

Comment: For IDE go for visual code, I feel its really simple. Ionic2 is based on angular2 but it has some tricks like instead of (change) you need (ion-change). I have released 2 apps in ionic2 but the thing is you need to note is not to update because changing breaking updates are always happening.

Comment: We are planing to develop in linux os. Is there any editor that can be implement the ionic2 in linux machine. How about atom editor?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the `Ionic2` tutorial http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/. I just upgraded my project to work with the latest version of `Ionic2`. They are using the Release Candidate 1 of `Angular2` (as of this writing), and they are continuously upgrading. It is fairly easy to get a project up and running following the instructions on their site.

I am using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) on my computer (they also have a version for Linux).

Comment: Web storm is paid. Do you have any suggestion for a free version?

Comment: I am following the same command as they have instruct here in the link. I have download the node latest version via the link https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/. But i am getting the error like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028810/cordova-installation-issue-on-windows-10

Comment: You could try [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) instead, but I do not have any experience with it, but I know many are using it. It says you need to buy it for a licence, but you can evaluate it forever, thus free.

Comment: An answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555054/cordova-wont-install-on-windows-10) says that you should try to use an older version of Node in order to make Cordova working with NPM. Maybe you could try to downgrade Node.js

Comment: Yes Just saw it. So i think i need only option to use the angular1 in cordova. Thank you guys for helpig to solve my issue.

Comment: You can still use Ionic 2 with Angular 2 even though you have to downgrade your version of Node. But of course, you can also use Ionic 1 with angular if it is less hassle.

Comment: but i doubt if go with the angular1 and in meanwhile if they are release the angular2 version do they inform a force upgrade to angular 2 or reduce the support for angular1.

Comment: No worries. Angular 1 will be in production continously updating